# Mount blade smaller map

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

Is there any way to spawn in a smaller battle map? It takes like 5 minutes of walking to start the battle. A mod that makes maps smaller would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TweakMB](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=101731.0) is a tool that allows you to mod your game.  It does many things, which includes increasing or decreasing the battle map size.